# Compile Python Program For Distribution

Tags: python, compilation

I've made a simple python application that I want to distribute for beta testing, I am on a windows computer and my beta testing Operating Systems include windows, mac, and ubuntu.

My question is how would I compile the program to a standalone application on Mac and Linux (Windows is already sorted)

Comment: I have a Mac, and in general I created a VM for Windows in order to create the .exe file, and use my Mac to generate the other two. 
The lib I use is https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/installation.html
Curious if someone found another solution for generating a multi-platform in an easy way, without using VMs

Comment: Take a look @imaGonneDie, I believe you won't be able to make it, but will check if out to understand if is possible to do so, anyways. 
In any case I'll answer with my code to generate executables using `pyinstaller`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292381/can-i-generate-a-python-executable-file-on-my-mac-that-can-be-used-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, you cannot create a standalone version of a Python program for a different OS then the one you're using for compiling.

I'm a Mac user, and when I want to generate a Windows Executable, I use a Windows that I installer at my VM, and compile from there. The same for Linux.

In any case, I use `pyinstaller` lib to generate an executable, which is really simple:

1. Install the lib: pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/installation.html

2. On your terminal, walk to the folder where is your `.py` file

3. Just type `pyinstaller --onefile filename.py`

4. 2 new folders will be created at the folder, `dist` and `build`. So just open the `dist` folder to find your executable

Here you see I use the `--onefile` parameter, and I find best, because without it, your `dist` folder will generate a folder full of content from each dependency and other aspects, and it's not neat to share this with users. With `--onefile` the users will only find one executable file.