# Convert py file to exe (windows) on a Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, exe

I have to convert py file to exe for some windows users. But I have Mac.

I tried pyinstaller myfilename.py but it generates only mac executable file in dist folder.

How can I convert py file to windows exe on a Mac Os

Answer (score 0):

Question already asked here:
[Can I generate a python executable file on my Mac that can be used on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292381/can-i-generate-a-python-executable-file-on-my-mac-that-can-be-used-on-windows)

Answer:
"You just can not generate Windows executable files on OS X.
You must use the platform which you want the program to run on to compile the program. If you own a copy of Windows, you could run a virtual machine on you Mac and compile it on that."

Comment: Is there any workaround? Accessing a windows machine or a vm is not an option for me

Comment: you install a windows VM on your mac and you try to build the executable in it.  You can find virtualbox here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and get some windows VM https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/.

Comment: Then you install https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/ to generate the exe

Comment: @Niha No there isn't a workaround. Python is not a compiled language and PyInstaller is not a compiler. What PyInstaller does is take the bytecode of your program, any library modules it uses, any binary dependencies (`.so`/`.dll` files) that they have, all data it expects, and a copy of your Python interpreter, and bundles them all into a huge self-extracting zipfile with a despatcher to unzip, install and run the code, and delete it afterwards. Does that explain why you have to construct the `.exe` on a platform similar to the target machine?